# $f(x) = \ln x$. Let $n \in \mathbb N^*$. Show that the restriction of the function $f$ on $[n, n+1]$ satisfies MVT's conditions.

Tags: calculus

I think this is a really stupid question but I have no clue what this exercise asks of me.

I don't understand what I need to show. I know that this theorem states that if a function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then there exists a $c$ so that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. What does the exercise ask then? Do I have to show that $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $[n,n+1]$?

Comment: Not sure why am I being downvoted, this is what the exercise asks word for word. If it is stupid then it's not my fault.

Comment: You probably misunderstood what I meant. I am saying that this question that I am asking (not the exercise question) might be stupid, but even though I think that I am still asking it because I don't know what else to do.

Comment: No problem, @Radu.  But you should give yourself more credit.  I hardly think your question is stupid.  As you suspected, I misunderstood what you meant (I thought you were calling the exercise stupid).  In any case, never hesitate to ask, or fault yourself for asking for clarification.

Comment: yes you just need to prove that $\ln(x)$ is differentiable (and continous) on $[n,n+1]$

Comment: @amWhy. Appreciate the kind words. It is hard to not hesitate asking questions like this on this site, there are some toxic people that really put me off sometimes.

Comment: @fGDu94 Thanks for clarifying it for me. $f(x)=\ln x$ is an elementary function so it is continuous and differentiable over its domain of definition, right?

Comment: yes that is correct. You can prove it is differentiable from first principles if necessary quite easily if you want.